# Compare output stream performance

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I have a serializable object and I want to write it down to file. Should I use `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` or convert it into a `byte[]` (using `ObjectOutputStream`) then use `FileOutputStream.write()`?

```
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))
objectOutputStream.writeObject(myObject);
```

or

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out;
out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
out.writeObject(myObject);
new FileOutputStream(file).write(byteOut.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Use the former (possibly [modified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60916218/6395627)). The second approach is convoluted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffering can improve performance by coalescing small writes into larger bulk writes. If you want to introduce buffering use a `BufferedOutputStream`, which does what you're doing with the byte array stream without changing downstream code.

```
// Unbuffered
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

// Buffered
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
```

This way you can continue to use `ObjectOutputStream` without the rest of the code having to know whether the stream is buffered or unbuffered.

As with any performance-related change, you should benchmark both approaches to see which performs better. Don't make changes like this without empirical testing. If you don't test, you're just guessing.